# ImportError: No module named remote

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create the following template tag on django:

```
from django import template
from django.utils import translation
from player.remote import MongoDb

register = template.Library()

@register.assignment_tag
def load_item(itemId):
  mongo = MongoDb.instance()
  return mongo['lol-%s' % translation.get_language()]['items'].find_one({'id': int(itemId)})
```

but whenever I try to load it, it always fails with the following error:

```
'items' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading tags.templatetags.items: No module named remote
```

Some notes:

- I can import the MongoDb using the manage.py shell
- My project path is on Python Path
- 'player' is currently on settings under 'INSTALLED_APPS' area.
- I've tried already: 'player.remote', 'remote', 'app.player.remote', 'teemo.app.player.remote', 'teemo.player.remote'
- I'm using the builtin server, since i'm still developing it
- I'm using django 1.8 with python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu

Structure (missing a lot of files, but in general):

```
teemo
  manage.py
  player
    __init__.py
    remote.py
  templates
    player
      resume.html <-- Importing 'items' tags
  tags
    templatetags
      __init__.py
      items.py
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried 'teemo.player.remote' ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to add that option there.

Comment: Yes it does work, already added that to the 'notes' on the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was attempting to overwrite the `items` tag, overwriting the dict `items` method.

In this scenario, it was looking for the `items` inside the dict, which is not what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `'teemo.tags'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in order for django to find your `templatetags`.

**Edit**

It also seems that you are missing: `teemo/tags/__init__.py` file.

Comment: tags is already under INSTALLED_APPS. I have several other tags that are fully functional, but for some strange reason 'player.remote' does not work.

Comment: My (hope to be) temporary solution was to simply create a new app and move the files there.

Comment: @AdrianoMartins How about an `__init__.py` file in the tags folder. :)

Comment: Already there! :( - I simply gave up and I'm using the temporary solution as official one, lol.